# Why I have to outlet all the labels to localize, what is the role of object id

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, translation

I am new to iOS and especially in objective C, I need to localise my app, after a lot of RND I have a confusion, why I need to create outlets of all labels to assign localised string. What is the role of object id's of labels that need to be assigned a localised string
I think there should be a solution that will work based on object id's.

if I am adding one more language, say Spanish and Base language is English
our project will have two files(Localizable.String(English) and Localizable.String(Spanish)) having same keys with crrosponding translated string. And after adding languages in target > info > localizations Storyboards extends to localised Sub Storyboards having object id's of all UIObjects

Now if assign Key from .String files to object id's, **How to localise strings runtime from inside app**

My question is same for both, objective c and swift (Now I need a solution for objective c)

Any tip, sample code, example, specially working example in objective c will be appropriated, thanks and Sorry if I failed to explain :)

I tried:

```
class LanguageManager
```

{

```
static let sharedInstance =  LanguageManager()

//Make a function for Localization. Language Code is the one which we will be deciding on button click.
func LocalizedLanguage(key:String,languageCode:String)->String{

    //Make sure you have Localizable bundles for specific languages.
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(languageCode, ofType: "lproj")

    //Check if the path is nil, make it as "" (empty path)
    path = (path != nil ? path:"")

    let languageBundle:NSBundle!

    if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path!)){
        languageBundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
        return languageBundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: "", table: nil)
    }else{
        // If path not found, make English as default
        path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("en", ofType: "lproj")
        languageBundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
       return languageBundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: "", table: nil)
    }
}}
```

Usage:

```
 logInLabel.text = LanguageManager.sharedInstance.LocalizedLanguage("LOGIN_LABEL_KEY", languageCode: "es")
```

**But I don't want to create outlets, I  want to just change String files .lproj to auometically localise **

Comment: Do you want the user to select a localisation in your app or do you just want iOS to localise your app based on the users current language setting?  The second is much easier. You simply localise your storyboards and use `NSLocalizedString` whenever you need a localised string in code.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. I want to localise from inside app runtime (with or without restarting App). without restarting app is more prefferable

Comment: Then you will have to do it the hard way. You will need outlets for everything in your storyboard and set the text programmatically. Apple strongly suggests you follow the iOS standard approach;  the user can select a specific language for your app independent of the system language using the preferences app if they don't want to change the device language.

Comment: @Paulw11 ,Ok. if I go with the device language, then do I still need to create outlets, or the object id's will work there?
if yes, How plz :) :And Thanks again for your consideration

Comment: If you use device localisation then you just localise the storyboard files that are created. You need to associate the appropriate localised strings with the object ids but you don't need to create outlets because you don't need to do anything in code. The only time you would need an outlet is if you did want to use something more complex, say where numeric quantities and plural rules don't have a straightforward translation.

Comment: @Paulw11 For this approach do I still need Localizable.String files?

Comment: Yes. That is where you put your localisations.